# How to insert Background Image in HTML email for OUTLOOK

Tags: html, email, outlook, vml

I have problems with background image of my email in Outlook. It isn't totally loaded.

I tried to use the code provided on bulletproof.com in vml but without success.

This is the code I use:

```html
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td background="http://image" style="background-image: url(http://image);">
          <!--[if(gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" 
             style=" border: 0;display: inline-block; width: 525pt; height: 825.25pt;" 
             src="http://image" />
             <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" 
             style=" border: 0;display: inline-block;position: absolute; width: 525pt; 
             height: 825.25pt;">
             <v:fill  opacity="0%" color="#f7901e"  />
             <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
              <![endif]-->
          <div>
            ........
          </div>
          <!--[if(gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
               </v:textbox>
               </v:fill>
               </v:rect>
               </v:image>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't working for you, there is either an issue with your image, the permissions with your hosted image or something else in your code is messing up display.

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width: 600px; height: 600px; background-position: center center !important;">
<v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkQH8.jpg" />
  <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->

<p>**Content Goes Here**</p>

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
  </v:textbox>
</v:rect>
<![endif]-->
```

What you should see in Outlook 2007-2019 is the image below in a 600x600px square.

[image: background image]

Good luck.

Comment: i tried to copy&paste your code in Litmus and send a test email and I dont see the background image

Comment: Hi @MarcoMirabile, I ran this code through Litmus this morning once again. I was hoping maybe there was an issue with imgur as an image host, but it works fine with Outlook 2007-2019. All I included was a very simple html wrapper and the vml code. I use this same code to send millions of emails to users, including Outlook. Could there be a conflict with your doctype? I am using `<!DOCTYPE html>`. I really wish I had an answer for you. Maybe post your entire code and lets see if there's something else causing the issue. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much for your tests. I wrong something for sure, I use `<!DOCTYPE html>` too. You can find the full code here [http://www.paolaredaelli.it/evento_email_ARTCITY.html]. How can i test email in outlook without having outlook installed (actually I'm on OSX)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've never really seen the  tag being used for background images - just a rectangle with a background image.

```
<td valign="top" align="center" background="IMAGEURL">
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:525pt;height:825.25pt;">
<v:fill type="tile" src="IMAGEURL" color="#FALLBACK COLOUR"/>
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
   <div>CONTENT</div>
<!--[if gte mso 9]></v:textbox></v:rect><![endif]-->
```

As stated - we're drawing a rectangle which has a background image instead of drawing a rectangle and image. Don't forget to change image URL's and the fallback colour - If you find your content rendering a bit wonky you can also play with the textbox inset which acts like padding. Unlike padding - values go left, top, right, bottom (as opposed to the standard top, right, bottom, left).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it doesn't work. Anyway what is the best way to send a html email? copy/paste the html page in gmail new message?

Comment: that's odd! How are you sending it, idealy you want to be able to use an email server or such a like. Have you tried test sending through something like Mailchimp to an outlook inbox?

Comment: I changed the type from "tile" to "frame" but when i send the email it becomes an image and i lost every links inside the email. I open the html page in IE, select all and copy, paste in outlook new message and when i receive it is just an image. I tried to send the email using Litmus and the background is't displayed in outlook. It is very frustrating managing html emails...